# Name for the maximum willingness to pay of other market participants

Tags: economic-terms

Suppose there is an auction for a unique good, say an original piece of artwork.  There are many potential buyers, including buyer X.  Each buyer has a unique reserve price, or willingness to pay.  If X's reserve price is the highest, then X wins the auction.  If X's reserve is not the highest, then X loses the auction.

Whether X wins or loses the auction depends on the *maximum willingness to pay of all other buyers*.  Is there a standard name for this quantity in economics?

Comment: The *highest competing bid* to X's?

Comment: @HerrK. I like the 'competing' part, but it's not quite actually an auction bid that I'm trying to get after.  It's the reserve price, which a buyer may or may not actually bid during the auction.  I suppose 'highest competing reserve' might work.